# Reverse for 'product_list_by_category' with arguments '('books',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: python, django

I have tried all the questions and answers on stackoverflow and read and write and rewrite my template, but I keep getting the error "Reverse for 'product_list_by_category' with arguments '('books',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['shop/(?P[-\W]+)/$']"

The full trace is here:

NoReverseMatch at /shop/
Reverse for 'product_list_by_category' with arguments '('books',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['shop/(?P[-\W]+)/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:3025/shop/
Django Version: 1.9.7
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:

```
Reverse for 'product_list_by_category' with arguments '('books',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['shop/(?P<category_slug>[-\\W]+)/$']
Exception Location: /home/namalliv/public_html/lib/python/Django-1.9.7-py3.4.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 508
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python3.4
Python Version: 3.4.4
Python Path:    
['/home/namalliv/public_html/villaproject',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/python_magic-0.4.11-py3.4.egg',
 '/home/namalliv/public_html/lib/python',
 '/home/namalliv/public_html/lib/python/Django-1.9.7-py3.4.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python34.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/plat-linux',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 5 Dec 2016 01:22:25 +0000
Error during template rendering

In template /home/namalliv/public_html/villaproject/templates/shop/list.html, error at line 22
Reverse for 'product_list_by_category' with arguments '('books',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['shop/(?P<category_slug>[-\\W]+)/$']
12  
13  {% block content %}
14      <div id="sidebar">
15          <h3>Catergories</h3>
16          <ul>
17              <li {% if not category %} class="selected" {% endif %}>
18                  <a href="{% url 'shop:product_list' %}">All</a>
19              </li>
20              {% for c in categories %}
21                  <li {% if category.slug == c.slug %} class="selected" {% endif %}>
22                      <a href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}">{{ c.name }}</a>
23                  </li>
24              {% endfor %}
25          </ul>
26      </div>
27      <dir id="main" class="product_list">
28          <h1>{% if category %} 
29                  {{ category.name }} {% else %}Products
30              {% endif %}
31          </h1>
32          {% for product in products %}
```

Here is my model.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,
    db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200,
    db_index=True, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering=('name',)
        verbose_name = 'caterory'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('shop:product_list_by_category', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

view:

```
def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None;
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=category)
    return render(request, 'shop/list.html', {'category': category, 'categories': categories, 'products': products})
```

Here is my urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[-\W]+)/$', views.product_list, name='product_list_by_category'),
```

my main urls.py is

```
url(r'^shop/', include('shop.urls', namespace='shop')),
```

And this is my template:

```
{% block content %}
    <div id="sidebar">
        <h3>Catergories</h3>
        <ul>
            <li {% if not category %} class="selected" {% endif %}>
                <a href="{% url 'shop:product_list' %}">All</a>
            </li>
            {% for c in categories %}
                <li {% if category.slug == c.slug %} class="selected" {% endif %}>
                    <a href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}">{{ c.name }}</a>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Please post the error message _with full traceback_ and also your main `urls.py`.

Comment: url(r'^shop/', include('shop.urls', namespace='shop')),

This is my main urls.py

Comment: There it is Selcuk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url pattern uses `\W` (uppercase `W`), which matches everything *except* alphanumerical characters. You need to change it to lowercase, so that it matches alphanumerical characters:

```
url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.product_list, name='product_list_by_category'),
```